# Отдельный layout компоненты vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, компоненты, vuetify

Пишу небольшое spa на vue. Если быть точным, пытаюсь повторить что-то вроде этого https://www.devjournalapp.com/. 
Хотел спросить как при определенном роуте(в данном примере '/welcome'), у них рендерится отдельная компонента без внешней обертки, ну то есть без меню и т.д.
Если авторизоваться то вроде все понятно: корневая компонента, слева навигация, справа router-view. Но на роуте '/welcome' этой навигации нет.
Надеюсь смог объяснить суть вопроса. 
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, сам разобрался. Интересно как сразу не додумался до этого. Если вдруг кому надо решение, то просто навигацию рендерим, если пользователь авторизован